# C# BlobClient different download method differences

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

There are currently two download methods in BlobClient that I see mostly used in examples:

- DownloadContentAsync
- DownloadToAsync

*DownloadContentAsync* explanation shows that it is the preferred way to fetch blobs that can fit into memory. *DownloadToAsync* explanation tells it uses parallel requests and writes content to file path or stream.

When I am downloading text files, I should probably just use *DownloadContentAsync*? So is *DownloadToAsync* more appropriate when I am dealing with larger files, like video files? Is there a clear way to distinguish which method should be used when or should you just use your own discretion when choosing between these two?

If there is also some other good information to know around this topic I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I am downloading text files, I should probably just use *DownloadContentAsync*? So is *DownloadToAsync* more appropriate when I am dealing with larger files, like video files? Is there a clear way to distinguish which method should be used when or should you just use your own discretion when choosing between these two?

**DownloadContentAsync**:

Yes, you are right. If you are downloading text files, it is recommended to use the **`DownloadContentAsync`** method. This method is optimized for downloading blobs that fit in memory.

For small blobs like text and JSON files, this easily provides the data as BinaryData, allowing you to frequently get commonly used basics like strings, streams, and bytes.

**Sample code:**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = "xxx";
    string containerName = "test";
    string blobName = "readme.txt";

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);

    await DownloadToText(blobClient);
}

public static async Task DownloadToText(BlobClient blobClient)
{
    BlobDownloadResult downloadResult = await blobClient.DownloadContentAsync();
    string downloadedData = downloadResult.Content.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded data: " + downloadedData);
}
```

**Output:**

```
> Downloaded data: Everyone knows that paper is made from trees. But
> when one looks at trees, one cannot imagine that something so soft and
xxxxxxx
```

[image]

**DownloadToAsync:**

When dealing with larger files, such as video files, the **`DownloadToAsync`** method is better appropriate because it uses parallel requests and sends material to a file path or stream.

**Sample code:**

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    string connectionString = "xxxxx";
    string containerName = "test";
    string blobName = "sample7.mp4";
    string localpath = "C:\\demo.mp4";

    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);
    await DownloadToStream(blobClient, localpath);

    Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
}

public static async Task DownloadToStream(BlobClient blobClient, string localFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath);
        await blobClient.DownloadToAsync(fileStream);
        fileStream.Close();
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Directory not found: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Download completed!
```

[image]

The above code Opens a local file stream, downloads the blob asynchronously, and then closes the file stream. As a sample, it downloaded a 5 MB mp4 file from Azure blob storage to my local environment.

**Reference:**

- [BlobBaseClient.DownloadToAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadtoasync?view=azure-dotnet)
- [BlobBaseClient.DownloadContentAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.downloadcontentasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Is there a good practise on how big a file should be that I should use DownloadToAsync? For example if I am dealing with PDF files where some are way bigger than others?

Comment: Hi @BladeZ How much the Pdf file size?

Comment: @BladeZ If you are dealing with PDF files where some are way bigger than others, you may want to use `DownloadToAsync` for the larger files and `DownloadContentAsync` for the smaller files.

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-download-files.